# Storing a sequence of Long efficiently in a file in Scala

Tags: scala, arrays, byte, binaryfiles, binary-data

So I have an association that associates a pair of `Int`s with a `Vector[Long]` that can be up to size 10000, and I have anywhere from several hundred thousand to a million of such data. I would like to store this in a single file for later processing in Scala.

Clearly storing this in a plain-text format would take way too much space, so I've been trying to figure out how to do it by writing a `Byte` stream. However I'm not too sure if this will work since it seems to me that the `byteValue()` of a `Long` returns the `Byte` representation which is still 4 bytes long, and hence I won't save any space? I do not have much experience working with binary formats.

It seems the Scala standard library had a `BytePickle` that might have been what I was looking for, but has since been deprecated?

Comment: I think you may have to define what you mean by efficiently. A million raw longs is 8MBytes (for some value of M). Is that too big for you, so that you want some compression?

Comment: The byte representation of a long is only one byte. But if you use it on values outside the range -128 to 127 you'll loose information.

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor: The byte representation of a long is only one byte? What? A Byte is represented by a byte, and a short is 2 Bytes, an Int is 4, and a Long is 8 Bytes long, isn't it? If you store it as Text, it depends on the size of the value, but an average Long of an even distribution of longs is much longer than 8 Bytes.

Comment: Ok, more precisely, Long.byteValue() returns a byte, which is one byte long, not 4 bytes as the question states.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An arbitrary `Long` is about 19.5 ASCII digits long, but only 8 bytes long, so you'll gain a savings of a factor of ~2 if you write it in binary.  Now, it may be that most of the values are not actually taking all 8 bytes, in which case you could define some compression scheme yourself.

In any case, you are probably best off writing block data using `java.nio.ByteBuffer` and friends.  Binary data is most efficiently read in blocks, and you might want your file to be randomly accessible, in which case you want your data to look something like so:

```
<some unique binary header that lets you check the file type>
<int saying how many records you have>
<offset of the first record>
<offset of the second record>
...
<offset of the last record>
<int><int><length of vector><long><long>...<long>
<int><int><length of vector><long><long>...<long>
...
<int><int><length of vector><long><long>...<long>
```

This is a particularly convenient format for reading and writing using `ByteBuffer` because you know in advance how big everything is going to be.  So you can

```
val fos = new FileOutputStream(myFileName)
val fc = fos.getChannel // java.nio.channel.FileChannel
val header = ByteBuffer.allocate(28)
header.put("This is my cool header!!".getBytes)
header.putInt(data.length)
fc.write(header)
val offsets = ByteBuffer.allocate(8*data.length)
data.foldLeft(28L+8*data.length){ (n,d) =>
  offsets.putLong(n)
  n = n + 12 + d.vector.length*8
}
fc.write(offsets)
...
```

and on the way back in

```
val fis = new FileInputStream(myFileName)
val fc = fis.getChannel
val header = ByteBuffer.allocate(28)
fc.read(header)
val hbytes = new Array[Byte](24)
header.get(hbytes)
if (new String(hbytes) != "This is my cool header!!") ???
val nrec = header.getInt
val offsets = ByteBuffer.allocate(8*nrec)
fc.read(offsets)
val offsetArray = offsets.getLongs(nrec)  // See below!
...
```

There are some handy methods on `ByteBuffer` that are absent, but you can add them on with implicits (here for Scala 2.10; with 2.9 make it a plain class, drop the `extends AnyVal`, and supply an implicit conversion from `ByteBuffer` to `RichByteBuffer`):

```
implicit class RichByteBuffer(val b: java.nio.ByteBuffer) extends AnyVal {
  def getBytes(n: Int) = { val a = new Array[Byte](n); b.get(a); a }
  def getShorts(n: Int) = { val a = new Array[Short](n); var i=0; while (i<n) { a(i)=b.getShort(); i+=1 } ; a }
  def getInts(n: Int) = { val a = new Array[Int](n); var i=0; while (i<n) { a(i)=b.getInt(); i+=1 } ; a }
  def getLongs(n: Int) = { val a = new Array[Long](n); var i=0; while (i<n) { a(i)=b.getLong(); i+=1 } ; a }
  def getFloats(n: Int) = { val a = new Array[Float](n); var i=0; while (i<n) { a(i)=b.getFloat(); i+=1 } ; a }
  def getDoubles(n: Int) = { val a = new Array[Double](n); var i=0; while (i<n) { a(i)=b.getDouble(); i+=1 } ; a }
}
```

Anyway, the reason to do things this way is that you'll end up with decent performance, which is also a consideration when you have tens of gigabytes of data (which it sounds like you have given hundreds of thousands of vectors of length up to ten thousand).

If your problem is actually much smaller, then don't worry so much about it--pack it into XML or use JSON or some custom text solution (or use `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream`, which don't perform as well and won't give you random access).

If your problem is actually bigger, you can define *two* lists of longs; first, the ones that will fit in an `Int`, say, and then the ones that actually need a full `Long` (with indices so you know where they are).  Data compression is a very case-specific task--assuming you don't just want to use `java.util.zip`--so without a lot more knowledge about what the data looks like, it's hard to know what to recommend beyond just storing it as a weakly hierarchical binary file as I've described above.

Comment: Index in the beginning of file means, SLOW appends. I would suggest a separate file for Integers, then. Also for `ByteBuffer` I would say `ByteBuffer.allocate(8*buffer.length)` - reuse buffer of smaller (!) then data, size. In a while loop.

Comment: @idonnie - Indexing this way at the beginning does mean slow appends, agreed; in that case you would have one more offset which would be be either `0L`, meaning we're done with blocks of blocks, or the offset of the next header/record chunk.  (Inspired weakly by the TIFF format.)

Comment: I mainly meant a code working with channels and buffers, like this one for reading (a part of prod code that does a HUGE data transfering): `do { add -= fromCh.read(bbuf); } while (bbuf.hasRemaining() && (add > 0));`. Anyway thanks for a TIFF idea, very memorable!

Answer (score 5):

See Java's [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html). It allows easy and efficient writing of primitive types and `Strings` to byte streams. In particular, you want something like:

```
val stream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("your_file.bin"))
```

You can then use the equivalent [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) methods to read from that file to variables again.

Answer (score 2):

I used `scala-io`, `scala-arm` to write a binary stream of `Long`-s. The libraries itself are supposed to be a Scala-way to do things, but these are not in Scala `master` branch - maybe someone knows why? I use them from time to time.

1) Clone `scala-io`:

`git clone https://github.com/scala-incubator/scala-io.git`

Go to `scala-io/package` and change in `Build.scala`, `val scalaVersion` to yours

`sbt package`

2) Clone `scala-arm`:

`git clone https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm.git`

Go to `scala-arm/package` and change in `build.scala`, `scalaVersion :=` to yours

`sbt package`

3) Copy somewhere not too far:

`scala-io/core/target/scala-xxx/scala-io-core_xxx-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

`scala-io/file/target/scala-xxx/scala-io-file_xxx-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

`scala-arm/target/scala-xxx/scala-arm_xxx-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar`

4) Start REPL:
`scala -classpath "/opt/scala-io/scala-io-core_2.10-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:
/opt/scala-io/scala-io-file_2.10-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:
/opt/scala-arm/scala-arm_2.10-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar"`

5) `:paste` actual code:

```
import scalax.io._

// create data stream
val EOData = Vector(0xffffffffffffffffL)
val data = List(
  (0, Vector(0L,1L,2L,3L))
  ,(1, Vector(4L,5L))
  ,(2, Vector(6L,7L,8L))
  ,(3, Vector(9L))  
)
var it = Iterator[Long]()
for (rec <- data) {
  it = it ++ Vector(rec._1).iterator.map(_.toLong)
  it = it ++ rec._2.iterator
  it = it ++ EOData.iterator
}

// write data at once
val out: Output = Resource.fromFile("/tmp/data")
out.write(it)(OutputConverter.TraversableLongConverter)
```